# When I send adb shell "am instrument command, the application terminate

Tags: android

I write a class extends Instrumentation and I want to call the function in the apk to run from shell command, the class is like this：

TestInstrumention.java

```
    package com.pg.service;

    public class TestInstrumentation extends Instrumentation {
    Bundle results = null;
    public static String[] moduleList = {"TestModule"};
    private ArrayList<String> moduleNameList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(moduleList));
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked","rawtypes"})
    private ArrayList<String> methodNameList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"None"}));
    public Context context = null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle extras){
        super.onCreate(extras);
        context = this.getContext();
        results = new Bundle();
        try{
            String request = extras.getString("request");
            if(request != null){
                JSONObject requestJs = new JSONObject(request);
                String module = requestJs.getString("module");
                String method = requestJs.getString(("method"));
                invokeModuleMethod(context, module, method);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, results);
    }
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml,I write like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.test.jp.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <instrumentation
        android:name="com.pg.service.TestInstrumentation"
        android:targetPackage="com.test"/>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test'
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

ok, all is this, when I send shell command like this：

```
    adb shell "am instrument -e request \"{module:test,method:testfunction,params:{}}\" -r com.test/com.pg.service.TestInstrumentation"
```

it show the result:

```
    INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: Method=testfunction
    INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: Module=test
    INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: Result=hello
    INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

all is run, but when the result showed, the application terminate, the logcat show this:

```
    03-25 09:50:28.723 1578-1590/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.test appid=10122 user=0: finished inst
    03-25 09:50:28.723 1578-1590/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 9879:com.test/u0a122 (adj 0): stop com.test
    03-25 09:50:28.724 1578-1597/system_process W/zygote: kill(-9879, 9) failed: No such process
    03-25 09:50:28.765 1578-1597/system_process W/zygote: kill(-9879, 9) failed: No such process
    03-25 09:50:28.765 1578-1597/system_process I/zygote: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10122 pid 9879 in 41ms
```

why the application is terminate?

I have been troubled for three days on this issue, and there is no clue

Comment: I may know what the reason is... because I called the    finish(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, results); at the last of onCreate(), but there are another question, how can I send the  adb command and get the return, the application not terminate? Is there a way?